# Adding site and bindings (with Host Name, Port, and IP Address) to IIS with appcmd

Tags: iis, cmd, appcmd

I am trying to use appcmd.exe to add a website to IIS.

I have almost everything working except one small bug.

The line of code I am using is

```
add site /name:WEBSITENAME /bindings:https://HOSTNAME:10.100.213.121:443 /physicalpath:C:\inetpub\WEBSITENAME
```

When I do this and look at the bindings on IIS it has everything correct except my ip address is shown to be "*:10.100.213.121" (excluding the quotes)

somewhere it is adding the *: to the beginning of it.

This is creating an invalid binding.

I want to keep this to only one command

I know I can use a second command to edit site bindings, but if i can keep this all the the creation of the site that would be ideal

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a syntactical issue with your **bindings** parameter to take note of which also indicates an answer to the question:

According to the [reference documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350(v=ws.10).aspx) The bindings parameter can be passed in the following format:

```
/bindings:http/*:85: -- note single slash after protocol
```

Your example indicates  the following format was used.

```
/bindings:http//*:85: -- note the extra forward slash after the protocol.
```

Hence:

**OPTION 1**

Perform the task as a single command:

```
 appcmd add site /name:WEBSITENAME /physicalpath:C:\inetpub\WEBSITENAME /bindings:https/10.100.213.121:443:
```

**OPTION 2**

Perform the task as a two phase commit.

1. creates the site (a variation of what you already have minus the binding info)
2. applies the binding configuration change required.

*The reason for the two phase commit in this example is due to the second command requiring a site to exist prior to the configuration change being applied.*

NOTE: The two commands are separated with **&** on the command line so they can be run as a single line.

```
appcmd add site /name:WEBSITENAME /physicalpath:C:\inetpub\WEBSITENAME & appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.applicationHost/sites /+"[name='WEBSITENAME'].bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='10.100.213.121:443:']" /commit:apphost
```

[Additional Documentation](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding)

Answer (score 1):

see below how I used to SSL port 443

appcmd set site /site.name:**NAME_SITE_IIS** /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:**443:yourdomain.com.br**']

Where it is in **bold**, change the information

Answer (score 0):

I tested it now as follows and it worked.

```
appcmd add site /name:test.com /physicalPath:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.com /bindings:http/192.168.0.1:80:test.com
```

I hope this helps you.